# python How to find my process See next

Tags: python, string, if-statement

My data is the snmp taken out, and now needs to find the process that I want.If the data inside the print OK, no process print critical.

my code the if statement is error.

r_e:data

val:my process

```
r_e=HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunName.384 = STRING: "csrss.exe" HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunName.408 = STRING: "winlogon.exe" HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunName.456 = STRING: "services.exe"
```

```
for i in r_e.split('\n'):
    data = i.split(': ')[-1].strip('"')
    print data
    if a.find(val) >=0:
        print "OK"
    else:
        print "Critical"
```

results  ./t.py

```
Critical
Critical
Critical
OK
Critical
Critical
```

i want results

```
./t.py 
Ok 
not
./t.py
Critical
Critical
Critical
OK
Critical
Critical
```

The problem has been resolved.

```
if r_c != 0:
    print "Critical - snmpwalk is Error."

else:
    processes = r_e.split('\n')
    programs = 0
    for program in processes:
        programFile = program.split(':')[-1].strip(' "')
        if programFile == val.split('!')[0]:
            programs = programs + 1
    if programs
```

Comment: So your program doesn't print anything at all?

Comment: @prelic i want to Show only OK

Comment: @prelic OST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunName.384 = STRING: "csrss.exe"
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunName.408 = STRING: "winlogon.exe"
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunName.456 = STRING: "services.exe"

Comment: This really needs an edit for clarity, I can't honestly even begin to decipher it to offer a suggested edit.  There's 2 'OK' print statements making it hard to follow which one is wanted, and there are poor variable names or non-conventional setups in bad pseudo-code to top it off.  This needs help, lots, and fast.

Comment: @Jeff Langemeier Friends, and now described in the clear?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the following ?

```
datas=[i.split(': ')[-1].strip('"') for i in r_e.split('\n')]
print [(d.find(val)>=0 and "ok") or ("my process %s not exist" % val) 
            for d in datas]
```

Comment: @  john wang  else:
    print "my process %s not exist" % val

Comment: Not what I want. my outputCritical
Critical
Critical
OK
Critical
Critical  i want to Show only OK